# How to refresh product page without reloading in Magento..?

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento

I want product page to get refresh only not to reload when customer click on the filter button..

Comment: Sorry to ask you the Question but i am not getting what you want to do ? I mean you want to refresh the page at specific interval?

Comment: I just want whenever customer click on the filter button the page get refresh only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you are doing well.

As off your issue is quite simple all you what to do is that you are required to fire ajax call and it must of the native js that is of Prototype so it would be easy for you.

Now when to fire the ajax call or call the java script function is that when the filter is clicked.

Example for ajax call in prototype and from that you can frame it in your code.

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
     sDate=($$('[name="startDate"]')[0].value)
     eDate=($$('[name="endDate"]')[0].value)
     pid=($$('[name="prodId"]')[0].value)
     new PeriodicalExecuter(function(pe)
                       {

                        new Ajax.Request('/index.php/productcountdown/index/timerDisplay', {
                        method: 'post',
                        parameters:{startdate: sDate, enddate: eDate, prodId:pid},
                        onSuccess: successFunc,
                        onFailure:  failureFunc
  });  
},3);
});
function successFunc(response)
{

     if (200 == response.status)
     {
            if (response.responseText=="true")
            {
                $("timerBlock").show();
            }
            else
            {
                $("timerBlock").hide();
            }
    }
}
function failureFunc(response){
}
```

In the above example i have given on load event all what to do is you call that on click of filter.

Hope this will make you day !!!

Cheers !!!

Waiting for you comments :) :) ;P